# Release() or factory destroy function in c++

Tags: c++, interface, coding-style

I'm writing a dll library in c++. It will only export few factory create function with some pure virtual interface. 
Now I'm wondering which design is better, for example we have something like this:

```
API_EXPORT IFactory* CreateFactory();
API_EXPORT Destroy(IFactory* pFactory);

class IFactory
{
  public:
  virtual InterfaceA* CreateA() = 0; 
  virtual InterfaceB* CreateB() = 0; 
  virtual InterfaceC* CreateC() = 0; 
  virtual InterfaceD* CreateD() = 0;
  // virtual void Destory(InterfaceA* p) = 0;
}
```

Let's say I obtain the interface from the Factory and I have 2 ways to delete it when finished.

```
IFactory* myFactory = CreateFactory();
InterfaceA* myInterface = myFactory->CreateA();
......
......
Method 1:
myFactory->Destroy(myInterface);

Method 2:
class InterfaceA
{
....
virtual void Release() = 0;
}
CImplementationA::Release()
{
    delete this;
}
myInterface->Release();
```

The second method seems more elegant since the user don't have to hold the myFactory object everywhere. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If there is a properly implemented virtual destructor, what is wrong with just using `delete`?

Comment: @jxh According to Don Box's *Essential COM*, virtual destructor has portability issues.

Comment: @jxh To be specific, Don Box said that virtual destructor *pollutes the compiler independence of the interface class, as the position of the virtual destructor in the vtbl can vary from compiler to compiler*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second method. Once an object has come into being, it should manage itself following the guidelines of OOP. I see no reason to give the responsibility of destruction to others like the factory function.